# Annotation processing failing with 'symbol not found' in Scala/Java interdependent build

Tags: java, scala, build, annotations, javac

I have a project that uses Java annotations to generate code. Since there is also Scala code in this project, I want to run my build in 3 phases:

1. Annotation processing (Java code generation)
2. Scala compilation
3. Java compilation

I'm trying to accomplish step 1 at the moment using javac's `proc:only` flag. I'm calling javac like this: `javac -processor org.my.processor -processorpath /path/to/processor.jar /path/to/annotated/file.java`

The code I want generated does in fact get generated and written to disk, but javac still insists on (seemingly) compiling my source files - the javac call fails with a bunch of `symbol not found` errors.

Does anyone know a) why the javac call is failing with "sumbol not found" despite the `proc:only` flag, and b) if there is another way I should be doing this?